# Save PowerPoint pptm to pptx

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am making my first steps in VBA.
I have been trying many things, but still I haven't figured out a way to save a .pptm powerpoint presentation to .pptx format with the same file name in a specific path?
I already use the following code to save as pdf.

`ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "c:\" + Replace(ActivePresentation.Name, "pptm", "pdf"), ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint, msoCTrue`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not just use `SaveAs` method to switch from PPTM to PPTX, see Cor's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic usage is:

```
With ActivePresentation
    .SaveCopyAs _
        FileName:=.Path & "\" & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".")) & "pptx", _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
End With
```

(Or you can use .SaveAs. SaveAsCopy keeps the current open and doesn't open the copy, whereas .SaveAs sets the current to be the saved version)

However, if the Powerpoint you are saving hasn't been saved at least once then the above will error (there is no file extension in Presentation.Name to find with InStrRev). You can either test for there being no full stop, or you can use a lazy method of asking FileSystemObject to get you the name without an extension (I am lazy so I prefer this method):

So a better more robust method is:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With ActivePresentation
    .SaveCopyAs _
        FileName:=fso.BuildPath(.Path, fso.GetBaseName(.Name) & ".pptx"), _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The 1st code works fine.
However, when the path is "\" it works fine and saves.
If i change the path to e.g. desktop it doesn't save.

Comment: @AlexBrown what do you mean by "Desktop"? "Desktop" itself isn't a path. A path without a drive is treated as a path relative to the current location. So "\" on its own would work as that would mean the current folder, but "Desktop" would mean a folder named "Desktop" within the current folder. Either way, glad it helped but if it did answer your question then please mark it as an answer.

Comment: @AlexBrown if you want to find the location of the desktop folder within the environment then you can use the WshShell object either via a reference or through CreateObject("WScript.Shell"). Once you have the object use: .SpecialFolders("Desktop"). this returns the path to the desktop as a string.

Comment: thank you for your tips. I thought that if I put the Desktop path: "C:\Users\username\Desktop" it would work fine as well, but it doesn't save.

Comment: @AlexBrown it definitely should do! Can you put a breakpoint or a Debug.Print, assign the full path to a variable and reply with exactly what it is trying to save it to? Thanks