# SaveAs PPTM to PPTX

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I need to turn a batch of pptm files into pptx. I tried to repurpose VBA code that turns xlsx files into xls files. The macro opens an xlsx file in a designated folder, saves it as an xls file, closes it, and moves on to the next file until all are converted. The original macro code was:

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname, saveFileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    Pathname = "<insert_path_here>"  ' Needs to have a trailing \
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
    initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Pathname & Filename, _
                            UpdateLinks:=False)
    wb.CheckCompatibility = False
    saveFileName = Replace(Filename, ".xlsx", ".xls")
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=Pathname & saveFileName, _
              FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

I modified it in the following way:

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname, saveFileName As String
    Dim ppPres As Presentation
    Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    Pathname = "\\TRIFS03\RoamingProfiles\user\Documents\projectfolder\testfolder\"  ' Needs to have a trailing \
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.pptm")
    initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Set ppPres = Presentations.Open(Filename:=Pathname & Filename, _
                            UpdateLinks:=False)
    ppPres.CheckCompatibility = False
    saveFileName = Replace(Filename, ".pptm", ".pptx")
    ppPres.SaveAs Filename:=Pathname & saveFileName, _
              FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    ppPres.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

I get

> Compile Error Named Argument Not Found

pointing to `UpdateLinks:=`.

I did some research and found that I should delete this bit of code. I was left with the following:

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname, saveFileName As String
    Dim ppPres As Presentation
    Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    Pathname = "\\TRIFS03\RoamingProfiles\user\Documents\projectfolder\testfolder\"  ' Needs to have a trailing \
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.pptm")
    initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set ppPres = Presentations.Open(Filename:=Pathname & Filename)
        ppPres.CheckCompatibility = False
        saveFileName = Replace(Filename, ".pptm", ".pptx")
        ppPres.SaveAs Filename:=Pathname & saveFileName, _
              FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
        ppPres.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

I got

> Compile Error Method or Data Member not Found

pointing to `.CheckCompatability =`.

I tried deleting THAT one.

> Compile Error Named Argument Not Found

pointing to `Password:=`.

I decided to look for a new macro:

```vb
With ActivePresentation
    .SaveCopyAs _
      FileName:=.Path & "\" & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".")) & "pptx", _
      FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
End With
```

I added loop code and ended up with:

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, FileFormat As String
    Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
        .SaveCopyAs _
          Filename:=.Path & "\" & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".")) & "pptx", _
          FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
        ppPres.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

Which ended up with

> Compile Error Invalid or Unqualified Reference

with `.Path` being pointed to as the culprit.
According to the [code’s author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289234/save-powerpoint-pptm-to-pptx) (see top voted answer), I shouldn’t need to define `.Path` if I’m using `\`.

Comment: Apparently you forgot in your last piece of code to reference **ActivePresentation**

Comment: @TSion.D.P thank you for commenting. How/where would I add code to reference `ActivePresentation` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, FileFormat As String
    Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActivePresentation
        Do While Filename <> ""

            .SaveCopyAs _
              Filename:=.Path & "\" & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".")) & "pptx", _
                                FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation

           Filename = Dir()
       Loop
   End With
   Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

Comment: I entered your code and tried running the macro. I did not receive any errors but...nothing happened. No files being saved, no opening and closing, nothing.

Comment: @dart852 That's because Filename is blank to start with and your loop only works while it's NON-blank. You need to use Dir(path,filespec) at least once before that to assign the first found file name to Filename.  Also, the code shown above doesn't open any files to process.  Have a look at some example code on my PPT FAQ site that should answer the need:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I've used your website for a few other macros! It's very helpful! Using your site I managed to get the macro working. Now I need to find code that also selects `Yes` on the pop-up that asks if I want to save the presentation as a macro-free presentation...

Comment: Been trying for the last few hours. While the converting code works, no line of code I've found seems to automatically stop the `To continue saving as a macro-free workbook, click Yes` pop up...

Comment: Actually @SteveRindsberg , I need this conversion because I used the SplitFile code on your website http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01086_Break_a_presentation_up_into_several_smaller_presentations.htm . Is there a way to make it save the copies as PPTX instead of PPTM??

Comment: Sorry for the continued comments. Solved it myself. The original file should be a `ppt` instead of `pptm` or `pptx` and then it all works out

Comment: @dart852 It'd work as well with a PPTX, I expect, and you could probably save PPTMs as PPT w/o it barking at you, though depending on what's in the file, you might lose some fidelity or find the files ballooning in size. Another approach might be to start a new file based on the same template then copy each slide from the original (PPTM) to the new file, which you save as PPTX. There's also a way of removing the macro code from the file under program control, I'm pretty sure, but have never gone there.